# extract object from array - typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, prop

I have a trip object that looks like this:

```
Array (1)
0 {id: 1, vehicle: {freeSeats: 2, __typename: "Vehicle"}, startLocation: "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[8.217462,53.13975]}", endLocation: "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[8.258844,53.119525]}", timeOfDeparture: "2020-06-16T11:48:00.869Z", …}
```

```
type TripListProps = {
  trips: any; //TODO FIX
  //trips: Array<Trip>,
  friendIds: Array<number>,
};

export const TripList: React.FunctionComponent<TripListProps> = ({ trips, friendIds }) => {
  console.log('trips', trips);
  if (trips.length > 0) {
    return ( 
      <View style={{ height: 500 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={trips}
          horizontal={false}
          scrollEnabled
          renderItem={({ item }) => <TripContainer trip={item} friendIds={friendIds} />}
          keyExtractor={(trip: any) => trip.id.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    )
  } else {
    return (<View style={styles.noTripsFound}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>No trips found</Text></View>);
  }
};
```

It's original type is `Array<Trip>`. However, here I am passing it to another component `TripContainer`, which requires trip to be in this form:

```
trip: {
  driver: {
      firstName: string;
      rating: number;
      id: number;
  };
  timeOfDeparture: any;
}
```

Because of this, if I change my `TripListProps`from `trips: any` to `trips: Array<Trip>`, I get an error.

Is there any way I can extract only this part from the whole array object?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `_.pick` in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick) to pick only those with keys

```
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };

_.pick(object, ['a', 'c']);
// => { 'a': 1, 'c': 3 }
```